# Laravel vagrant unable to mount

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

Obviously after some updates, my whole dev environment broke. When running `vagrant up` I get the following error:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attemped was:

set -e
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

: No such file or directory
```

I have tried with several options on StackOverflow, as well as googling, but no help. I've installed the `vagrant-vbguest` plugin, I've updated, destroyed and provisioned the box, I did a `vagrant reload --provision`.

I've also tried logging in to guest with SSH, and running `sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions`

Does anyone have a solution?

**EDIT**:

I've tried downgrading Virtualbox to 5.1. and then I get the following:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "dc09e643-896d-4491-8a6a-659c13d2cf65", "--natpf1", "tcp8000,tcp,,8000,,80", "--natpf1", "tcp44300,tcp,,44300,,443", "--natpf1", "tcp33060,tcp,,33060,,3306", "--natpf1", "tcp54320,tcp,,54320,,5432", "--natpf1", "ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: A NAT rule of this name already exists
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057), component NATEngineWrap, interface INATEngine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "AddRedirect(Bstr(strName).raw(), proto, Bstr(strHostIp).raw(), RTStrToUInt16(strHostPort), Bstr(strGuestIp).raw(), RTStrToUInt16(strGuestPort))" at line 1820 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same problem as you and my virtual box version was 5.1.16 all i had to do was downgrade to 5.1.14 and problem fixed.
Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work. I've reinstalled vagrant now, I don't know if I can downgrade laravel/homestead box somehow...